# Updating SQL once a day (on first user login) fails

Tags: php, sql, pdo, datediff

I have a login system and I want to increase a database value of a logged-in-user by 1, but only if it is the users first login of the day.

You can imagine it like getting a point for your daily login.

The way I am trying to do this is by using `WHERE`, `AND` and `datediff`:

First:

```
$add1point4login = "UPDATE accounts 
    SET points = points + 1, lastpoint = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name']."'";
```

Using the above works perfectly fine:
the `points` are increased by `1` and the `lastlogin` gets updated with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but the user could get endless points by just logging out and in again.

So I want to check the difference between the `lastpoint` timestamp in my database and the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and only give a point if the difference between the days is >0.

so I added the `AND` and started to use `datediff`:

```
$add1point4login = "UPDATE accounts 
    SET points = points + 1, lastpoint = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name']."' AND (datediff(accounts.lastpoint,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP>0)";
```

Now it doesn't work anymore.
Neither do the points get increased by one, nor does the `lastpoint-timestamp` gets updated...
which would be the desired outcome if the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would be the same day as the stored timestamp in `lastpoint`, but not if the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is `2021-11-19 21:21:36` and the stored one is `2021-11-17 21:21:36`.

I don't really know what next, maybe I am just completely blind rn. ~.~

Thank you!

Comment: You have the arguments to `datediff()` in the wrong order.

Comment: Side note: Use prepared statements with parameters, don't concatenate strings into the SQL.

Comment: will check the argument order to `datediff()` and I am using prepared statements:
`$query2 = $pdo->prepare($add1point4login); $query2->execute();` Thanks for the hint tho :)

Comment: But you're not using parameters. It should be `WHERE username = :username` and then `$query2->execute([':username' => $_SESSION['name'])`

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I totally overlooked that I get a negative value comparing the arguments in that order. And also thanks for your further help with prepared statements. This is my working code now:

`$add1point4login = "UPDATE accounts SET points = points + 1, lastpoint = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE username = :username AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, accounts.lastlogin)>0"; 
$query2 = $pdo->prepare($add1point4login);
$query2->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['name']);
$query2->execute();`